# show that $\partial_u(f \circ g)=f'(g(x))\partial_ug(x)= f'(g(x))(\nabla g(x) \cdot u)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

> Let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued differentiable function. If $g :\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, show that $$\partial_u(f \circ g)=f'(g(x))\partial_ug(x)= f'(g(x))(\nabla g(x) \cdot u)$$ where, $u$ is an unit vector.

I cannot seem to get this to work. It pretty much uses only the chain rule(?), but the notation confuses me a lot. How should I go about this?

Comment: Look up the meaning of $\partial_u$ in your source! This $u$ is not a further real variable, but a tangent vector at $x$.

Comment: By the problem statement $u$ was a unit vector!

Comment: What can you use? If you can use the chain rule then this is a consequence of $\partial_u \phi = u\cdot\nabla\phi$, which holds whenever $\phi$ is differentiable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could can use the chain rule here. @JackozeeHakkiuz

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Could you elaborate what is the name of this property so I can find more info of it $\partial_u \phi = u\cdot\nabla\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your source uses the notation
$$\partial_u\phi(x):=d\phi(x).u\ ,$$
where $u$ is any tangent vector, maybe a unit tangent vector, at $x$. This means that $\partial_u$ is considered as [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) in direction $u$.

We now are given a composition $f\circ g$ with $g: \>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ and $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. For such functions one has
$$dg(x).u=\nabla g(x)\cdot u,\qquad df(y).v=f'(y) v\ .$$
The chain rule therefore gives
$$\eqalign{\partial_u(f\circ g)(x)&=d(f\circ g)(x).u=df\bigl(g(x)\bigr).(dg(x).u\bigr)\cr &=f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\bigl(\nabla g(x)\cdot u\bigr)\ .\cr}$$

Comment: With $d\phi(x).u$ you mean the directional derivative in the direction of $u$? If so how come in the book they noted this with the symbol $\partial_u$, seems weird...

Comment: In my experience, $\partial_u\phi(x)$ denotes the partial derivative at $x$ in the direction $u$, while $d\phi(x)\cdot u$ or $\nabla\phi(x)\cdot u$ denotes the gradient of $\phi$ evaluated at $x$ and then dotted with $u$. Of course these two notions coincide for a differentiable function.

Answer (score 2):

A matricial view helps to settle your confusion: for a composition
$$\mathbb R^3\stackrel{g}\to\mathbb R\stackrel{f}\to\mathbb R$$
then generically $(f\circ g)'=f'(g)\cdot g'$ is the chain's rule,
and particularization would be
$$\nabla (f\circ g)=f'(g)\cdot\nabla g.$$
If use $x,y,z$ as the coordinated function on $\mathbb R^3$ and $t$ on $\mathbb R$ then
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial x}
&
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial y}
&
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial z}
\end{array}\right]=
\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
&
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
&
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}
\end{array}
\right]$$
which implies
$$\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial x}=\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
\quad,\quad
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial y}=\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
\quad,\quad
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial z}=\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}
.$$
But if you want a directional derivative in the direction
$\mathbf u=u^1\vec i+u^2\vec j+u^3\vec k$
then
$$\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial\mathbf u}=
u^1\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+
u^2\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}+
u^3\frac{df}{dt}(g)
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of $t$, what is it actually representing?

Comment: $t$ is the Independent variable in $\mathbb R$